# Apply filters to a table based on conditions using LINQ and MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to create a list of records (partners) based on a several list of conditions. The problem is that the SQL generated by the LINQ is selecting partners that respect at least one of the conditions, and I only want the partners that respect the conditions that have to be applied (serviceId or/and brandId and/or TraillerService).

Models (simplified):

```
public class Partner
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartnerServiceBrand> PartnerServiceBrands { get; set; }

}

// A partner can have multiple services, brands and in each case, can have, or not have trailler service
public class PartnerServiceBrand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Partner Partner { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }

    public bool TrailerService { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartnerServiceBrand> PartnerServiceBrands { get; set; }
}

public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartnerServiceBrand> PartnerServiceBrands { get; set; }
}
```

I want to apply conditions based on filters that I have:

```
IQueryable<Partner> partners = dbContext.Partners;

if (search.ServiceId > 0)
{
    partners = dbContext.Partners.Where(p => p.PartnerServiceBrands.Select(psb => psb.Service.Id).Contains(search.ServiceId));
}

if (search.BrandId > 0)
{
    partners = partners.Where(p => p.PartnerServiceBrands.Select(psb => psb.Brand.Id).Contains(search.BrandId));
}

if (search.TrailerService == true)
{
    partners = partners.Where(x => x.PartnerServiceBrands.Any(y => y.TrailerService == true));
}
```

The query that I get is:

```
SELECT[Extent1].[Id] AS[Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS[Name]
    WHERE(EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS[C1]
    FROM [dbo].[PartnerServiceBrands] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Partner_Id]) AND([Extent2].[Service_Id] = 7)
                        )) AND(EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS[C1]
                                        FROM [dbo].[PartnerServiceBrands] AS [Extent3]
                                        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent3].[Partner_Id]) AND([Extent3].[Brand_Id] = 1153)
                        )) AND(EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS[C1]
                                        FROM [dbo].[PartnerServiceBrands] AS [Extent4]
                                        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[Partner_Id]) AND(1 = [Extent4].[TrailerService])
                        ))
```

With this query, I get the partners that have a least 1 service with trailer service, and that's not what I want. I want only partners that respect all the conditions.

Comment: You are querying two different tables Partner_Id and PartnerServiceBrands.  So you need to join the two tables and then filter the joined results.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Hi thanks! Would you like to suggest an example for my case?

Comment: You need to join classes by Ids.  I can't tell from classes if all the Ids are the same, or which classes use the same ids and which are different ids.

Comment: I am trying to do it but I am unbale to merge the results from previous joins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to generate where condition without multiple if condition using linq query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730713/how-to-generate-where-condition-without-multiple-if-condition-using-linq-query)

Comment: @Fran As you can see in my code, I think I am doing the same, and the result is the query that I have included in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var baseQuery = db.PartnerServiceBrands.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

if(filterTrailer.hasValue){
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(x=> x.TrailerService == filterTrailer.Value);
}

if(filterServiceId.hasValue){
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(x=>x.ServiceId == filterServiceId); 
}

if(filterServiceId.hasValue){
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(x=>x.BrandId == filterBrandId); 
}

var results = baseQuery.Select(x=>x.Partner)
                       .ToList();
```

TODO: add also a group by to not have duplicated Partners. Adapt the final "Select" to obtain the necessary extra info you need.

Comment: Hi thank! It's working fine! It seems that I was filtering the wrong entity Partners->PartnerServiceBrands

Answer (score 0):

flip your logic around.

```
if (search.ServiceId == 0)
{
    return new Partner[] {};
}

if (search.BrandId == 0)
{
    return new Partner[] {};
}

if (search.TrailerService != true)
{
    return new Partner[] {};
}

return dbContext.Partners
    .Where(p => p.PartnerServiceBrands
                 .Select(psb => psb.Service.Id)
                 .Contains(search.ServiceId))
    .Where(p => p.PartnerServiceBrands
                 .Select(psb => psb.Brand.Id)
                 .Contains(search.BrandId))
    .Where(x => x.PartnerServiceBrands
                 .Any(y => y.TrailerService == true));
```

Comment: so you need all three qualities to be false to fall through to perform the full query.  if any of the 3 tests fail, you are returning an empty list. So what I did is flip the logic of your tests.  if your service id comes in as 0 then return an empty list.  if BrandId is 0 return an empty list.if.... Once all those checks are passed. run the full query. with all 3 predicates. That code could be cleaned up into 1 Where clause, but you can chain them together as i did.

Comment: The issue here I think, is that the tests are all in the same class method

Comment: why is that an issue?

Comment: Because I am trying to understand what happens when I don't have a brandId for example, and with the return new... I will exist the method, correct?

Comment: it will, with an empty list, because in your question you state "partners that respect all the conditions."  So in the case where we find a condition we don't meet, we fail fast and return an empty list.  and we only drop through to the full query if all conditions are met

Comment: So sorry about that, the conditions can be any

Comment: that's a completely different question

Comment: I have changed the text to "I only want the partners that respect the conditions that have to be applied (serviceId or/and brandId or/and TraillerService)."